# nodejs - get folder structure recursively and synchronously

Tags: node.js

I have folder structure like this:

```
project
   |app
      |util
   |sass
   |image
      |icon
```

I want to get this structure recursively and synchronously

The expected result

```
[
 app,
 app/util,
 sass,
 image,
 image/icon,
]
```

Is there is any npm can do this? or probably some way to do this?

Comment: there are multiple ways to achieve this. what did you try yet?

Comment: I tried fs.readdirSync('dir'). That's not recursively.

Answer (score 0):

So there is npm package that can do this

`npm i --save-dev glob`

```
import glob from 'glob'

let dirs = [
        ...glob.sync('app/**/'),
        ...glob.sync('sass/**/'),
        ...glob.sync('image/**/')
        ]
dirs = dirs.map( item => item.replace(/\/$/, ""))
console.log(dirs)
```